# Implementing magic method in the Queue class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Am trying to implement python Queue class which need a magic method in the Queue class.Am getting the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
Enqueue 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

### File "C:/Users/NGAHU-MWANGI/Desktop/lab10.py", line 64, in

```
main()
```

[1]
  File "C:/Users/NGAHU-MWANGI/Desktop/lab10.py", line 55, in main
    numbers += 15
[2, 1]
  File "C:/Users/NGAHU-MWANGI/Desktop/lab10.py", line 22, in **iadd**
[3, 2, 1]
    for i in other.container:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'container'
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

### Dequeue one item

[5, 4, 3, 2]

### Deque all items

Item dequeued: 2
[5, 4, 3]
Item dequeued: 3
[5, 4]
Item dequeued: 4
[5]
Item dequeued: 5
[]

```
class Queue:
def __init__(self,numbers=None):
    self.numbers=[]

 def is_empty(self):
    return self.numbers == []

 def enqueue(self, number):
    self.numbers.insert(0,number)

 def dequeue(self):
    return self.numbers.pop()

def __iadd__(self,other):
    for i in other.container:
        self.add(i)
    return self

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.numbers)
# -----------------------------------------------------

def main():
numbers = Queue("Numbers")

print("Enqueue 1, 2, 3, 4, 5")
print("---------------------")
for number in range(1, 6):
    numbers.enqueue(number)
    print(numbers)

print("\nDequeue one item")
print("----------------")
numbers.dequeue()
print(numbers)

print("\nDeque all items")
print("---------------")
while not numbers.is_empty():
    print("Item dequeued:", numbers.dequeue())
    print(numbers)

# Enqueue 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
for number in range(10, 15):
    numbers.enqueue(number)

# Enqueue 15
numbers += 15
#numbers.enqueue(15)

print("\n10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 enqueued")
print("-------------------------------")
print(numbers)

 # -----------------------------------------------------

main()
```

Comment: You *did* read the implementation, right?

Comment: yes i did. But am trying to understand how to implement a method for this  statement  numbers += 15